# How to XOR numbers together then extract a number

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor, bitwise-xor

Let's say a, b, c are three integers.
Then XOR them together and get d = a ^ b ^ c.

If I only know "a" and "d", and there is no relationship between a, b, c. Is there a way to check if "a" has been used to produce "d"?

For example:

```
d = a ^ b ^ c;

func(a, d); //returns true

func(b, d); //returns true

func(f, d); //returns false, for f!=a, f!=b, f!=c
```

I mean "d" is the result of "a^b^c", and we don't know that in advance. Now given "d" and a number "x", can I check if x is one of a or b or c?

Sorry I forget to mention that a, b, c, d are NOT boolean variable here. I use them to stand for integers in any programming language. So d = a^b^c is a bitwise operation. For example, d equals to the result of 2^18^19.

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: Sorry, there is no actual code. I just want to implement a function which could check if d is produced from a given number.

Answer (score 1):

No, because for *any* a and d, you can make the equation true, e.g. by setting b = 0 and c = a ^ d.

For example, let's take your example, where d = 2^18^19. You want func(12, d) to be 'false', because 12 is not equal to 2 or 18 or 19. The problem is that d is just 3; it doesn't "remember" having been made from 2 and 8 and 19 at all. So d = 2^18^19 = 3 = 12^0^15 = 7^12^8 = 4^11^12 = …, and there's no reason, given just d = 3, to view 12 or 0 or 15 or 7 or 8 or 4 or 11 as being any different from 2 or 18 or 19.

Comment: Oh you probably misunderstood my question. 
I mean d is a^b^c.

Comment: Oh you probably misunderstood my question. 
I mean d is the result of a^b^c. Now given d and a number x, can I check if x is one of a or b or c?

Comment: @fishlinghu you still can't, for the same reason. There is no possible check, it is always the case that `x` *might* have been a or b or c, no matter the values of `x` and `d` you can always choose the other variables such that it works out.

Comment: @fishlinghu: I understood your question perfectly. For *any* `a` and `d`, `d == a ^ b ^ c` for some `b` and `c`. (In fact, for any `a`, `b`, and `d`, `d == a ^ b ^ c` is true for some `c`.)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot: for any couple of numbers (a and d) you can always find another number (b) that XORed with one of the numbers in the couple gives the other.

`d = a ^ b or a = d ^ b`

Moreover you are trying to do it with multiple XOR...

XOR is in fact used as a primitive method of encryption. You could try and guess that if you had a lot of numbers d created through XOR searching for a pattern.